# Can I play Fallout: New Vegas without Steam?

Tags: pc, steam, fallout-new-vegas

I just bought Fallout: New Vegas today on Amazon for the computer and I am dying to play it, but for some reason it made me install it on Steam and it is now updating the game which it says will take 5 hours.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: If you don't update the game, you're going to have a lot of glitches.

Comment: yes, definitely would not recommend playing New Vegas unpatched.  Even after patching I'd recommending grabbing the unofficial new vegas patch mod.

Comment: RE: glitches and unofficial patch mods mentioned. OP might want to try the mod [NVEC - New Vegas Enhanced Content](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/mods/44204), which aims to fix the remaining unpatched glitches in FNV.

Answer (score 20):

Fallout: New Vegas uses [Steamworks](http://www.shacknews.com/article/64175/fallout-new-vegas-pc-using) as its DRM solution, and therefore it requires Steam in order to play.  Regardless of where you purchase it, you'll have to install Steam and install it via the Steam client in order to play it.

Comment: In other words, "Because that's how Obsidian and/or Bethesda decided it would work."